# Is there a way to get IE to render CYMK images

Tags: cmyk

I put images on our website that were very nice in Firefox and little red x's in IE.  I understand that IE wants only RGB and I could convert my images.  In fact I tried it out.  The issue is that the images get dulled down, look dead in RGB.  I'm hoping that there is some way to say, IE load these images in RGB, but Firefox load these other images in CMYK.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can get IE to render CMYK encoded images.  To avoid manually changing them, you could put a filter on the site to automatically convert them but I would assume that the quality would suffer.

CMYK encoding is typcally used for print, which as quality requirements that are overkill for the web.  With a decent quality photo editing tool, such as photoshop, you should be able to get decent, web quality, versions of these photos using RGB encidong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to find, it's not currently possible to get IE to use a CMYK format (perhaps with an add-on?).

Your conversion process may not be saving the most optimal color setting. Perhaps using a different conversion mechanism (i.e. a different tool) from CMYK to RGB would help.

Link: http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3885754.htm